# alias not working as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I am trying to get [file types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1842270/1772898) using an alias. I am using:

```
alias file-types="find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u"
```

However, it is not working:

When I type the command in the terminal it shows (which is exactly what I want):

```
azw
azw3
bz2
chm
epub
pdf
```

but when I use the alias, it shows something like:

```
./x.epub
./y.pdf
./z.pdf
.....
```

What can I do to make this command an alias.

Comment: Your reference is from SO. Why not ask the question there? Generic programming questions are usually handled well there and unless ubuntu specific a better resource to use.

Comment: The perl bit can be shorter (perhaps simpler?) -- `perl -ne 's/.+\.// && print'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the outer double quotes allow `$1` to be evaluated by the shell when the alias is defined, so `print $1` becomes plain `print` :

```
$ alias file-types="find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u"
$ alias file-types
alias file-types='find . -type f | perl -ne '\''print  if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/'\'' | sort -u'
```

Probably the simplest way to fix the quoting is to backslash-escape the `$`:

```
print \$1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/
```

**however** I'd recommend using a shell function in place of an alias for cases like this - see for example [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)